# how to get value of only checked checkboxes on clicking either li or checkbox itself wrapped with ul li using map()

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Im trying to get the value of checked checkboxes using jQuery map function and it is working fine. The thing is: when I wrapped the `input`s (type checkbox) with `ul` `li` then I am not able to get the values of checked checkboxes. Also I want user to click either on checkbox itself or `li` tag to check the checkboxes. My attempt so far:

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="get">
    <ul class="chk">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="India" />India</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="Pakistan" />Pakistan</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="UK" />UK</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="USA" />USA</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="Russia" />Russia</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chk li').click(function(){
        var c = $(this).children();

        var check = $(c).map(function(){ 
            check.attr('checked','checked');
            return this.value;
        });
        console.log($(check));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something using `map()`:

```
$('.chk li').click(function (e) {
    var innerCheckbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
    if (e.target != innerCheckbox[0]) {
        innerCheckbox.prop('checked', !innerCheckbox.prop('checked'));
    }
    var check = $(this).parent().find(':checkbox:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value; // or return this;
    }).get(); // <---------- calling get() to get a basic array

    console.log(check); // array with the values of the checked ones
});
```

It will check the checkbox if the **target of the event** is the `li`. After that, it will select the list of checked checkboxes and `map()` their values into the `check` array.

[**See demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/NjD3L/2/).

Comment: However, the solution you have given worked for me and I really appreciate it but is there something similar using map()? Thanks anyway..:)

Comment: There you go, I updated the code to use `map()`. The demo was also updated.

Comment: So I was missing this chunk of code: if (e.target != innerCheckbox[0]) {
        innerCheckbox.prop('checked', !innerCheckbox.prop('checked'));
    }
    var check = $(this).parent().find(':checkbox:checked') Thanks! this is really awesome. Thanks again...:)

Answer (score 0):

To enable click on the label use:

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="ch1" value="India" />
   <label for="ch1">India</label>
</li>
```

The rest is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chk li').click(function(){
        var c = $(this).children(':checkbox');

        var check = $(c).map(function(){ 
            return this.checked ? this.value : undefined;
        });
        console.log(check);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work for me, however, I have tried this before posting my question into SO:(- Have you tried it?